# WCF performance: Having multiple instances (separate websites) in IIS of same service make sense?

Tags: wcf

In order to improve performance* of a WCF service, one of the following can be done:

1. Use WCF inbuilt features (throttling etc)
2. Install multiple instances (separate websites in IIS) of the same service in the same machine.

I understand that these things are better tested than discussed but just wanted to get an opinion if someone has already tried both these approaches.

This service uses InstanceMode.PerSession and ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

Performance: This service handles data (MTOM encoded). There should not be any timeouts since clients will make synchronous calls to this service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, multiple endpoints from a single service won't help, as you describe it.

Yes, you can have a running WCF in IIS with multiple endpoints, but the same service is processing the requests whether they come into endpoints 1, 2, 3 or n. And since WCF requests are processed on their own threads, there's no benefit to adding extra end points.

Think of it this way: 10 requests come into a WCF service. Each request is processed on its own thread whether there are 10 endpoints or just 1. So there's no speed advantage gained by adding endpoints.

I've spent 2 years building industrial-scale WCF services. If you're worried about performance, the WCF service is the least of your worries. I've load tested a WCF service, sending 1000 concurrent users (each uploading multiple 157kb files) at a medium size (4 core) server; the server barely breaks a sweat while uploading 160 files/second.

If you're planning to build huge web service, the way to spread out the processing load is to have 1-n WCF web services fronted by a load balancer like F5. Then you can scale up to Amazon.Com size if you like.

Comment: Thanks Brian, this sounds logical. +1 for sharing performance testing stats.